# JQuery Selection of required fields

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors

I am trying to figure out why my jquery selection doesn't work but I've tried several things and couldn't get it run. I hope you might be able to give me a hint:

Here's the HTML-Part:

```
<div id="collapseOne" class="panel-collapse collapse in">
    <!--CONTACT FORM-->
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-6 col-sm-12 left">
            <label>Company</label>
            <input type="text" id="smpcheckout_customer_company" name="smpcheckout[customer][company]" class="form-control not-removable" />
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-6 col-sm-12 left">
            <label>&nbsp;</label>
            <div class="input">
                <input name="title" type="radio" value="mr">
                <label>Mr</label>
                <input name="title" type="radio" value="mrs">
                <label>Mrs</label>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-6 col-sm-12">
            <label>First Name*</label>
            <input type="text" id="smpcheckout_customer_first_name" name="smpcheckout[customer][first_name]" required="required" class=" not-removable" />
        </div>
```

Here's the JS-Part. :

```
$("#buttonone").click(function () {
  $('#collapseOne').find('input').filter('[required]').each(function () {
    if (!$(this).val().length) { //works only for text
      $(this).parent.prepend("<strong>Please fill out this field</strong>");
```

Anyways, while debugging I see that it doesn't select even one field although nothing has been entered...

Thanks a lot for your help and suggestion.
Steffen

Comment: `parent` is a method. You are missing `()`.

Comment: Dear Vohuman. Thanks for the hint, I changed this accordingly. This is definitely true but not the cause of the issue as it is not selecting anything. Do you have another idea? Thanks!

Comment: Can you provide a jsfiddle that reproduces the problem?

Comment: Dear Vohuman.The Problem is solved. The solution was : .filter("[required='required']"

Comment: Well, if `.filter("[required='required']")` works then `.filter("[required]")` should also work. The latter selects elements that have the specified attribute.

Answer (score 0):

The Problem is solved. The solution was : .filter("[required='required']" –

Answer (score 0):

You could do it this way:

```
$("#buttonone").click(function () {
    $("#collapseOne input[required]").each(function () {
        if (!$(this).val().length) { //works only for text
            $(this).parent().append("<strong>Please fill out this field</strong>");
        }
    });
});
```

Noticably, you could select the `required` using `#collapseOne input[required]` instead of finding and filtering.

[jsFiddle for reference](http://jsfiddle.net/rison/va5nnnb9/)